# is there a possibility to pop up a wx.message_dialog on top of a chrome browser which opened by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wxpython

im trying to open chrom and then asking the user for closing the chrome, so i tried to do it with wx, but for some reasons which i dont know SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP) isnt working when i using selenium.

i've tried to create a wx.message_dialog using the flag: style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP
but its not working so i tried also to change the window style by SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
but still its not working

```
import wx
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title = "ffffffff")
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
        self.driver = None
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        self.SetWindowStyle(no_resize)
        button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Show MessageDialog", (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.Show(True)


    def OnButton(self, event):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1'+':5000')
        time.sleep(3)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        stopBox = wx.MessageDialog(self , "do you want to stop","stop controling", style=wx.YES | wx.NO | wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        stopBoxAns = stopBox.ShowModal()
        if stopBoxAns == 5103:
            stopBox.Destroy()
            no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
            self.SetWindowStyle(no_resize)
            return 1
        if stopBoxAns == 5104:
            stopBox.Destroy()
            no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
            self.SetWindowStyle(no_resize)
        return 2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below behaves itself on Linux.
As I mentioned before, STAY_ON_TOP carries a warning that it is "currently implemented only under MSW and GTK" and you have not said what you OS is.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title = "ffffffff")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.no_resize = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        self.SetWindowStyle(self.no_resize)
        button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Show MessageDialog", (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnButton(self, event):
        wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser('https://wxpython.org/')
        #self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        stopBox = wx.MessageDialog(self , "do you want to stop","stop controling", style=wx.YES | wx.NO | wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        stopBoxAns = stopBox.ShowModal()
        ret_value = 0
        if stopBoxAns == wx.ID_YES:
            ret_value = 1
        if stopBoxAns == wx.ID_NO:
            ret_value = 2
        stopBox.Destroy()
        self.SetWindowStyle(self.no_resize)
        return ret_value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: im currently using windows but MessageDialog.stay_on_top works just if the frame is also STAY_ON_TOP.

Comment: in adittion do you know how can i close chrome with wx insted using selenium?

Comment: Don't know never used it. Are you saying that `self.driver.quit()` doesn't work? That's what the first webpage I looked up suggested.